# Create SQL summary using union

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I currently have some SQL that is used to create an excel report in the following format:

```
COL1    COL2     COL3
  2       1        8
  3       7        9 
  1       2        4
```

Now what I am trying to do is sum up the total of these each value and insert it at the bottom using `UNION ALL` (unless of course there is a better way.)

Now the values for each column are generated already by sums. The concept I can't grasp is how to sum all the values for the final row, if this is even possible.

So the output should look like so:

```
COL1    COL2     COL3
  2       1        8
  3       7        9 
  1       2        4
  6       10       21
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to add

```
 WITH ROLLUP
```

to the end of your query

eg:

```
Select sum(a) as col1, sum(b) as col2
from yourtable
group by something
with rollup
```

Depending on the full nature of your query, you may prefer to use `with cube`, which is similar. See [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh wow really? That simple? I thought I'd have needed a union. I'll have a look at that, thanks.

Comment: Great answer thanks, I could also use to have averages in there too, but hey-ho.. Can't have it all

Comment: yeah with rollup i am unable to get exact results even though sum is getting accurate

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
from tableA

union

select 
    sum(col1)
    ,sum(col2)
    ,sum(col3)
from tableA

order by col1,col2,col3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
    FROM SomeTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(COL1), SUM(COL2), SUM(COL3)
    FROM SomeTable
```

note. there is also a ROLLUP clause but I think the above would be a simpler solution in this case
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx